# Do I need these incoming open ports?

Tags: security, firewall, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm currently tightening up our Windows 2008 R2 Web server's software firewall rules. There are 4 open ports which I am not sure whether I need them or not:

```
Name: Windows Backup (RPC), Port: RPC Dynamic Ports
Name: Windows Backup (RPC-EPMAP), Port: RPC Endpoint Mapper
Name: Windows System Resource Manager (DCOM-In), Port: 135
Name: Windows System Resource Manager (TCP-In), Port: RPC Dynamic Ports
```

- Regarding windows backup ports: I guess I don't need these since the server simply backups itself onto a local hard disk and management of backups is done through remote desktop
- Regarding Windows System Resource Manager: I am not sure what this is or why I would need open ports to it.

Should I leave the ports open, or should I close them?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: which firewall? the built in one that comes with the OS? or a hardware fw thats public facing?

Comment: @Nick Kavadias: The one that comes with the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is a part of a LAN network with other trusted Microsoft computers, allowing these ports on the LAN side is safe. But if it's your only server and if this firewall is the only one between you and Internet, keeping them opened is a kind of security flaw.